# Find out which IDs don't already exist from an array of IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've got an array of IDs and I'd like to query to see which of those IDs don't already exist.

Take this:

```rb
spotify_ids = ['47k5tMDS3jLAOFE29nkfzO', '5mv8xuH3y6jxFCBT6a3w4K', '5En0gXQk01BaWoT4q2oVbe', '0cj44N6Ux4i2NkTkQIcLnE']

existing_items = Track.where(spotify_id: spotify_ids)
```

In this example, the ID `0cj44N6Ux4i2NkTkQIcLnE` does not exist, so what I'm ultimately trying to have returned is just `['0cj44N6Ux4i2NkTkQIcLnE']`.

That `where` just returns the records it finds, and I'm trying to pinpoint the which of those IDs it *doesn't* have saved.

I tried `Track.where.not(spotify_id: spotify_ids)` but that just returned every record from the entire table that didn't match those IDs, which isn't what I'm after.

At most, the array would have 50 items in it so, generally speaking, performance issues shouldn't crop up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the lists are so short...

First, get the existing IDs. Use [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/) to fetch just an array of IDs. This avoids the cost of fetching all the data and loading it into objects.

```
existing_spotify_ids = Track.where(spotify_id: spotify_ids).pluck(:spotify_id)
```

Then simply [subtract](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-2D) one Array from the other.

```
missing_spotify_ids = spotify_ids - existing_spotify_ids
```

If there can be duplicates you may need to use [`distinct`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-distinct) on the query and/or [`uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) on `missing_spotify_ids`.